# Floating figures with 'b' ends up below the footnote

Tags: floats, positioning, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tables below footnotes, is this a good output routine algorithm or a bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/tables-below-footnotes-is-this-a-good-output-routine-algorithm-or-a-bug)

Whenever a page contains a figure which is set to be placed at the bottom of the page, and the page also contains a footnote, the figure ends up below the footnote. I don't like this appearance; it looks odd and gives a feel that the figure belongs to the footnote instead of the main text.

How do I fix so that the footnote stays at the bottom of the page, and the figure is placed on top of it, even when its positioning marker is set to `b`? Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [%
      draw,
      rectangle,
      fill=black,
      minimum size=5mm,
    ] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5] more\footnote{Bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Yes, my drawing skills are awesome.) =)

Comment: This is a behavior I personally like. However, `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` is what you are looking for. But probably it's best to avoid bottom floats where footnotes are used.

Comment: Also look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/tables-below-footnotes-is-this-a-good-output-routine-algorithm-or-a-bug

Comment: Actually, this question is exhibit A for the (potential) usefulness of tags. You (quite correctly) choose the tags [tag:floats], [tag:positioning], and [tag:footnotes]. Well ... there's only one other question featuring all these tags, and it's the question Yiannis linked to.

Comment: @lockstep: I did a text search for "float footnote" and "figure footnote", but I didn't consider doing a tag search. I'll remember that till next time. =) This question can be closed, then.