# Odd behaviour when setting bottom margin

Tags: floats, positioning, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tables below footnotes, is this a good output routine algorithm or a bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/tables-below-footnotes-is-this-a-good-output-routine-algorithm-or-a-bug)

I use

```
\documentclass[liststotocnumbered,bibtotocnumbered,12pt,a4paper,Arial]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
```

I have no idea why LaTeX places one of my figures beneath a footnote:

[image: OddBehaviour]

Removing the `bottom`-setting form `geometry` places the figure to the correct position. However, I need to set the bottom margin to 20mm and don't know which default-setting the `scrbook`-environment uses.

```
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
```

[image: CorrectPosition]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/tables-below-footnotes-is-this-a-good-output-routine-algorithm-or-a-bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a bottom float appears on a page, LaTeX places the footnote above it. To prevent this you can load the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package with its `bottom` option:

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```