# Prevent the insertion of figure after the footnote

Tags: floats

How can I prohibit putting figure after the footnote? I have pretty simple LaTeX code that has a lot of figure environments, and I see the figure is inserted after the footnote.

```
\documentclass[10pt, onepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

... dependent code\footnote{You should use at least JRE 1.5 or later, but I highly recommend using JRE 1.6 or later}, you can safely use the JRE 1.5 or later. 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic_install/4_configure_build_path.png}
\caption{Configuration menu}
\label{fig:config_build}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is to load the `footmisc` package with the `[bottom]` option:

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

For some interesting discussion of the rationale behind the standard behaviour, see:

- [Tables below footnotes, is this a good output routine algorithm or a bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32951/2693)

Comment: Also, as [Ulrike Fischer have said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324719/142706), you can use the `\feetbelowfloat` command in preamble if using `memoir` class.