# Footnote number mark appearing twice when forcing to the bottom of the page with footmisc

Tags: floats, footnotes

I have a figure at the bottom of a page in my paper. I wanted a footnote to appear under the figure (the default behavior is that the footnote goes on top of the figure). [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114289/prevent-the-insertion-of-figure-after-the-footnote) said that adding `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` would force the footnote to go below the figure, which worked. However, now the footnote number appears twice, once above the figure alone, and then one below it in its rightful place in the footnote. Here's an image. I've censored the text + graphic as the research is as of now confidential, and have circled the footnote numbers for reference.

[image]

Here's what my code looks like for the figure and footnote:

```
\begin{figure}[b!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{filepath.png}
\caption{TEXT}
\centering
\end{figure}

\footnote{TEXT}
```

Let me know if you know of any way to remove the first "2" (after text from body). Thanks.

Comment: This answer seems to do what you're looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264157/217223

Careful, the associated comments to that answer carry some important warnings on side effects...

Comment: @agryson Hmm, I guess that could work as a last resort. But i'd really like to preserve the number if possible.