# how to position footnote in bottom of page and under figure in ieee trans template?

Tags: floats, templates

how to position footnote in bottom of page and under figure in ieee trans template?[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}%
}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vfill\kern -3pt \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth \kern 2.6pt}

\usepackage{stfloats}
\fnbelowfloat
%\feetbelowfloat
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{b}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{10pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
    \kern-3\p@
    \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
    \kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
bla bla



Sigma\footnote{asq.org/quality-resources/six-sigma} 
bla blabla

\begin{figure*}[b] \centering \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{method} \caption{Proposed Methodology} \label{fig:method}
\end{figure*} 

bla bla \footnote {apis.guru/graphql.voyager:}


Bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing any code we can only guess, sorry. Please add the short TeX code resulting in your shown screenshot to your question ...

Comment: @ Mensch Six Sigma\footnote{https://asq.org/quality-resources/six-sigma}  bla blabla
\begin{figure*}[b]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{method}
 \caption{Proposed Methodology}
 \label{fig:method}
\end{figure*} bla bla \footnote {http://apis.guru/graphql.voyager:}

Comment: \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} not work

Comment: this also don't solve the problem:
\usepackage{stfloats}
\fnbelowfloat

Comment: Please add a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927), otherwise hardly anybody will be able to help you here. Thank you.

Comment: the same issue in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114289/prevent-the-insertion-of-figure-after-the-footnote/623355?noredirect=1#comment1556192_623355 but dont't solve my question

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes i do it above