# Wide table in twocolumn document at the bottom of the page but above the footnotes

Tags: tables, floats, footnotes, two-column

According to the title I wish to insert a wide table into a twocolumn-style document at the bottom of the page. I had found `package` `stfloats` for it. However the `table*` will be placed below the footnotes and neither

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

helped me.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\let\endtitlepage\relax

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
\author{Me}%
\title{My title}%
\maketitle%
]
\section{One}\indent
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{footnote1}

\section{Two}\indent
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Three}\indent
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]\footnote{footnote2}
\lipsum[8]

\begin{table*}[b!]
\centering
\caption{Some caption}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
Name    & Terhelés  & $HV_{mean}$   & $\Delta_{AVG}$    & $\delta_{AVG}$    & db    & SD    & $\Delta$  & $\delta$  & IQR \\
NA1-es  & 10     g  & 170.7 & 5.6   & 3.3\% & 19    & 15.4  & 21.0  & 12.3\%    & 20.0 \\
NA1-ss  & 10     g  & 259.4 & 14.0  & 5.4\% & 14    & 24.3  & 38.3  & 14.8\%    & 31.7 \\
NA8-es  & 10     g  & 177.2 & 13.3  & 7.5\% & 5 & 22.6  & 35.9  & 20.3\%    & 39.8 \\
NA8-ss  & 10     g  & 318.6 & 25.1  & 7.9\% & 8 & 20.1  & 45.1  & 14.2\%    & 0.0 \\
NA13-es & 10     g  & 221.5 & 20.6  & 9.3\% & 4 & 22.4  & 43.0  & 19.4\%    & 30.4 \\
NA13-ss & 10     g  & 389.5 & 47.6  & 12.2\%    & 4 & 9.2   & 56.8  & 14.6\%    & 5.6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{Four}\indent
\lipsum[10]\footnote{footnote3}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

Does someone know the solution?

Comment: [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33030/579) is relevant, although the question isn't really.

Comment: Now, I'm the "somebody who finds this infelicitous" but the package `footmisc` didn't help with option `bottom`...

Comment: i was thinking more about the explanation of why footnotes are considered more appropriate *above* tables or figures at the bottom.  your problem is more complicated -- latex simply doesn't handle float placement at the bottom of double-column layouts.  perhaps some of the ideas in this question [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430) might help, but setting the table not as a float, but "in line" and manually entering a blank area in the right column.