# Avoid bottom floats on pages with footnotes

Tags: floats, footnotes

Following an [old discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33030/28685) about relative positioning of bottom floats and footnotes ("*bottom floats above or below footnotes?*"), I'd like to avoid altogether bottom floats on pages that also have footnotes.

Is it possible? Very simple question for a maybe hard answer.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: The hard par is getting bottom floats at all.   One could modify `\footnote` to `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{0}` and `\footnoterule` to `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}` (default).  Have to test it, of course.

Comment: Alas, you have to set bottomnumber on the previous page for it to work.  It can still be done, but than means using the aux file and everypage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo My TeX knowledge is not sufficient to fully understand what you mean, can you explain it more extensively, maybe with an answer?

Comment: @JohnKormylo better to use `\suppressfloats[b]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the great answer from John Kormylo. This version is more robust: If the text with the footnote comes at the end of the page, John Kormylos version can break because a footnote after a pagebreak might suppress the float on the former page instead. This can be avoided by moving the code into the output routine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.75in,paperheight=7.25in,
            textwidth=4.5in,textheight=6.5in,
            headsep=0.1in, footskip=0.15in,
            marginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\toks0{\ifvoid\footins\else\suppressfloats[b]\fi}
\output\expandafter{\the\toks0\the\output}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{latin}
\chapter{Errora}

Una\footnote{translatio via google} imagine\footnote{translatio via google} tabula\footnote{translatio via google}, figura\footnote{translatio via google} et\footnote{translatio via google} \ae\footnote{translatio via google} nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
Una\footnote{translatio via google} imagine\footnote{translatio via google} tabula\footnote{translatio via google}, figura\footnote{translatio via google} et\footnote{translatio via google} \ae\footnote{translatio via google} nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
Una\footnote{translatio via google} imagine\footnote{translatio via google} tabula\footnote{translatio via google}, figura\footnote{translatio via google} et\footnote{translatio via google} \ae\footnote{translatio via google} nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
Una\footnote{translatio via google} imagine\footnote{translatio via google} tabula\footnote{translatio via google}, figura\footnote{translatio via google} et\footnote{translatio via google} \ae\footnote{translatio via google} nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
Una\footnote{translatio via google} imagine\footnote{translatio via google} tabula\footnote{translatio via google}, figura\footnote{translatio via google} et\footnote{translatio via google} \ae\footnote{translatio via google} nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Uno pictorum} 
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[b]%[htbp] %uncomment to see difference
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \toprule
  Error &Errors &error &errors\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
  \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For beginners and readers in a hurry, to be clearer, in order to avoid bottom floats on pages with footnotes **just add to the preamble** the two lines `\toks0{\ifvoid\footins\else\suppressfloats[b]\fi}` and `\output\expandafter{\the\toks0\the\output}`.

Comment: Unfortunately the snippet wasn't able to do its job for one of my documents, I'll post a MWE as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5):

Tip of the hat to David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.75in,paperheight=7.25in,
            textwidth=4.5in,textheight=6.5in,
            headsep=0.1in, footskip=0.15in,
            marginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\let\oldfootnote=\footnote
\def\footnote{\suppressfloats[b]\oldfootnote}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{latin}
\chapter{Errora}

Una imagine tabula, figura et \ae nigma.\footnote{translatio via google}.  
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Uno pictorum} 
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[b]%[htbp] %uncomment to see difference
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \toprule
  Error &Errors &error &errors\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
  \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: So the two lines in the preamble `\let\oldfootnote=\footnote` and `\def\footnote{\suppressfloats[b]\oldfootnote}` did the trick. Great, thanks!

Comment: Having verified that the other solution is more robust, for correctness towards future readers I have to accept the other answer, although your contribution, as Marcel Kruger also remarks, was crucial. Thanks again.

Comment: @mmj - No problem.  I tested it and it definitely works better.  OTOH, I can't figure out how it works.  I know \output is used to split paragraphs, add footnotes and floats, but \toks0?