# Place Bottom Floats over Footnote without Footmisc Package

Tags: floats, positioning, footnotes, figure-placement

I'm redefining the footnote layout and want to have them displayed *always* at the bottom of the page. For pure text it was easy by putting an `\vfill` at the beginning of the `\footseprule` definition; like suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573538/force-footnotes-to-bottom-of-page-in-plain-tex).

If I have a document with many and long footnotes, bottom floats (`[b]` option) get placed below the footnote (which is standard in article.cls). I've tried to surpress bottom floats on pages with footnotes, like suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436004/avoid-bottom-floats-on-pages-with-footnotes). But when every page contains footnotes, the bottom floats are still placed below.

How can I achieve that bottom floats are *always* placed at the bottom of the textarea *but* above the footnote(rule); **without** using any additional package, especially `footmisc` (which is the solution most often advised to similar questions), or another class.

Here my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfill%
    \kern-3\p@ \hrule \@width \textwidth \kern 2.6\p@ \kern 2\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext[2]}

\begin{figure}[!b]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext[7]}

\blindtext[3]\footnote{text}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Reading `footmisc.sty` again and taking the ideas of @JohnKormylo and @UlrikeFischer into account, I tried modifing `\@makecol` by rearranging the parts. Since, as far as I understand it, `footmisc` places the output of the `footnote` after `\@combinefloats`:

Part from `footmisc.sty`:

```latex
\def \@makecol {%
  \@kernel@before@cclv
  \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
  \@outputbox@removebskip
  \let\@elt\relax
  \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
  \global \let \@midlist \@empty
  \@makecol@appendblocks
% Here the blocks are appended; i.e. a floatblock and a footnoteblock
  \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
  \else
     \@makenormalcolbox
  \fi
  \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
```

I tried it in a quite simple version:

```latex
\gdef \@makecol {%
    \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
    \let\@elt\relax
    \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
    \global \let \@midlist \@empty
    \@combinefloats
    \ifvoid\footins
    \else
            \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
            \unvbox \@cclv
            \vskip \skip\footins
            \color@begingroup
            \normalcolor
            \footnoterule
            \unvbox \footins
            \color@endgroup
    \fi
    \ifvbox\@kludgeins
    \@makespecialcolbox
    \else
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
        \@texttop
        \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
        \unvbox \@outputbox
        \vskip -\dimen@
        \@textbottom
    }%
    \fi
    \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
```

Indeed the bottom float now appears right after the textarea. But all footnotes are pushed to the top of the next page. Thus, the approach may be show the right direction, but one has to fix the placement of the footnotes...

I'll keep trying and am thankful for hints or solutions by others!

Comment: You will need to modify `\output`.  The key question is: are there any convenient hooks available?

Comment: well as \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} probably is doing what you want, you could study the code and copy the relevant parts. Personally I would use footmisc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo in the (experimental) latex-lab code the output routine has been changed and there are/will be configuration points that can be used, but they aren't yet in standard latex.

Comment: From sourc2e.pdf, its seems footnotes are added by `\@makecol` before running  `\@combinefloats`.  Also, it adds the entire `\footins` to the text then removes the excess back.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that what I did so far. But the code oft `footmisc` is kind of hard to understand for me in this case. I also guess, like @JohnKormylo suggested, that it has to do with `@makecol`. But couldn't figure out so far how to get it working

Comment: yes handling the output routine is hard. So why don't you use footmisc?

Comment: First of all, I want to learn how LaTeX/TeX handles such things in general. Furthermore, if I use the packages later, I understand better what they are doing and how to modify things; if necessary. Of course, I tried different things before posting the question here, also for learning purposes. Last but not least, at the moment, I'm writing a class file ans want to reduce the usage of packages as much as possible. In case of `footmisc` the latter may not be necessary. But in general, the more packages I load, the higher the chances that some options/aspects can collide.

Comment: well you currently have to patch internal core commands of the output routine to change the footnote placement. The danger that your manual patches collides with other packages or future development in this area is high. Here it is much better to use footmisc which is maintained by a LaTeX team member who really knows what is going on here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. Understanding the output stuff is too much right now. Maybe another day. For now i'll use `footmisc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there appeared some ambiguities when trying to patch the `\@makefntext` macro with `etoolbox` while using `footmisc` package, I came back to my own question.

I just studied the `footmisc` package a little more detailed and was able to edit the footnote definition, as well as the output routine to meet all my requirements. It contains an adapted variant of `\@makefntext`, pushes the footnote to the bottom of the page and places floats *always* above footnotes; even if they contain the `[b]` option.

I tested the code with the follwoing MWE, as well as with some more complex documents including sections, lists, pictures, citations, very long footnotes etc. So far, I couldn't detect any problem or conflict:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
% Editing footnotes to meet my formatting requirements
\newbox{\@fnbox} % New box for FN number
\newcommand*{\indent@fnmark}{2.5em} % indention between FN number and FN text
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% Redfinition of FN
            \bgroup
            \setbox\@fnbox\hbox{\hb@xt@\indent@fnmark{\@thefnmark\hss}}
            \leftmargin\wd\@fnbox
            \rightmargin\z@
            \linewidth \columnwidth
            \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
            \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
            \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
            \leavevmode
            \llap{\box\@fnbox}%
            #1
            \par\egroup}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfill%
    \kern-3\p@ \hrule \@width \textwidth \kern 2.6\p@ \kern 2\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}

% Changing the output routine
\gdef \@makecol {%
    \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
    \let\@elt\relax
    \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
    \global \let \@midlist \@empty
    \@combinefloats % floats are placed before footnotes (\footins)
    \ifvoid\footins
    \else
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
            \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
            \unvbox \@outputbox
            \vskip \skip\footins
            \color@begingroup
            \normalcolor
            \footnoterule
            \unvbox \footins
            \color@endgroup}%
    \fi
    \ifvbox\@kludgeins
    \@makespecialcolbox
    \else
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
        \@texttop
        \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
        \unvbox \@outputbox
        \vskip -\dimen@
        \@textbottom
    }%
    \fi
    \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{Some Text}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext[5]}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[4]\footnote{text}
\end{document}
```

[image: document with working footnotes while using floats etc]

Of course, despite my comprehensive testings there may be some hidden flaws. If someone notices such a conflict, I would be happy if he/she gives me a hint.